# Remove excess points on fingers and hand using python3 and opencv (cv2)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

[image]

I am doing measurement on hand palm and fingers project. I use convex hull and convexity defects to detect the fingertips and draw the points which I will use it for measurement later. Refer to the picture, u can see they are more than one points on the fingertips(thumb, small finger, index finger,etc), I want to remove them and left only one point on each fingertip. I tried to apply extreme point but I can only apply to extreme north,south,east and west. I searched the previous papers, they are using K-curvature angle but I don't know how ... can you help me,please? if you have any idea how to do measurement, feel free to guide me. I think of using the triangle similarity to calculate it.

```js
from imutils import contours
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

image=cv2.imread('oo.jpg')
image = imutils.resize (image,height=700)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)
edged = cv2.threshold(gray, 45, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=2)
edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=2)

cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
hull = cv2.convexHull(c,returnPoints = False)
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(c,hull)

for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
    s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]
    start = tuple(c[s][0])
    end = tuple(c[e][0])
    far = tuple(c[f][0])
    cv2.line(image,start,end,[0,255,0],2)
    cv2.circle(image,far,5,[0,0,255],-1)

cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.imwrite("Image.jpg",image)
cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF== ord("q")
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This might work: If two points in the convexhull are too close to each other, take their average. Do this until no two points are too close to each other. This means you should come up with a threshold for the distance between two points.

Comment: @dhanushka is it possible for you to show me how you do it?

Comment: I mean, something like this assuming hull contains points, 
`for(i=0;i<len;i++){ if(dist(hull[i],hull[(i+1)%len])<T){ hull2.append((hull[i] + hull[(i+1)%len])/2); } } hull = hull2;` This is just a pseudo-code. You'll have to repeat this process till the length of the hull stops changing.

Comment: @dhanushka oh, I got it. Try it out now, thank you very much sir^^